# UITableView crash when inserting rows from within "cellForRowAtIndexPath"

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've spent hours figuring this out.  In the end, I had to create a small test project to isolate the problem.  Briefly, I was having a weird crash that would "randomly" occur when I scrolled through my `UITableView`.  The crash only occurred when I was scrolling fast *and* was inserting rows into the `UITableView`.  (I batch new data in when the user is near the end of the table view).  The crash occurred within the `UIKit` framework:

```
Fatal Exception: NSRangeException
*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 15 beyond bounds [0 .. 14]
 raw
0   CoreFoundation  __exceptionPreprocess
2   CoreFoundation  -[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:]
3   UIKit    -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport(Private) _setupAnimationsForExistingVisibleCells]
4   UIKit    -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport _setupAnimations]
5   UIKit    -[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:]
6   UIKit    -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:]
```

My datasource and the tableview aligned perfection (this was not a book keeping error on my part).  So I created a test project and replicated the error.  What I found was that *if* I insert rows from directly within `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, the crash would occur:

```
import UIKit

let batchSize = 30
let cellID = "CellIdentifier"

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  var datasource: [Int] = Array(0..<batchSize)
  let tableView = UITableView()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    tableView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellID)
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[v]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: [ "v" : tableView ]))
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[v]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: [ "v" : tableView ]))
  }

  private func insertNewBatch() {
    let newData = Array(datasource.count..<datasource.count + batchSize)
    datasource += newData
    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(newData.map{ NSIndexPath(forRow: $0, inSection: 0) }, withRowAnimation: .None)
  }
}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDataSource {
  func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int { return 1 }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { return datasource.count }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellID, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Cell \(datasource[indexPath.row])"
    if datasource.count - indexPath.row < 10 {
//      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.insertNewBatch()
//      }
    }
    return cell
  }
}
```

However, *if* I `dispath_async` the method call on the main thread (essentially placing the call *after* the cell is returned) the crash does not occur.

In my main project, the batch loading process could return synchronously, thus essentially originating from within the `cellForRow...` delegate method... albiet through several frameworks.  Most of the time it was asynchronous, giving the appearance of being random.

My question is this: Is this a bug I should report?  I'm not aware of any place where `UITableView` forbids modifying the table from within the delegate methods, but I want to make sure this isn't known/expected behavior before I file.  Plus, I thought it might be helpful for other SO members if they ever have this issue.

Comment: Its not a bug. You cannot go mutating the tableview and/or its data source in the middle of an operation (i.e. a delegate method). The aync call is perfect!

Comment: Do you know of any place in the docs that forbid it?  If not, perhaps this is where I should file a radar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to expand on what David H said.

This is not a bug. iOS needs to finish populating the table with data that is immutable during population. It has already made a call to see how many rows should be in the table, how tall each cell should be, how many sections there are, etc. because it precalculates certain things before it presents the UITableViewCells.

If you change this on the current thread, all of those calculations will mismatch, leading to an error. There are specific cases where it may NOT throw an error (potentially if the data is changed in such a way that the number of cells is the same, height is the same, etc), but it will most certainly will for what you're doing.

Calling it asynchronously means that the data is only changed in the eyes of the UITableViewDelegate / UITableViewDataSource AFTER it has gone through all of the necessary calculations to populate the UITableView.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense and is what I thought.  However, I could not find anywhere in the documentation where Apple says this behavior is not valid.  So I'm wondering if I should file a bug on the documentation instead?

Comment: From the UITableViewDocs about reloadData: "It should not be called in the methods that insert or delete rows, especially within an animation block implemented with calls to beginUpdates and endUpdates." and since your function is already in the middle of a reload...

Comment: If this satisfies your answer, please don't forget to upvote and mark as correct for future users!

Comment: It wasn't exactly in the middle of a reload as much as insertion, but the point is well made.